# Highcharts chart not respecting container's width

Tags: javascript, highcharts, element-ui

I'm using highcharts inside tabs from Element UI framework and on first load the chart is always exceeding the parent container. How can I fix this ?

It seems the chart renders before its container is affected by the tabs rendering and making it smaller. I'd be interested to know if I can ensure Highcharts always laods after Element UI.

Also I know I can reflow the chart after but there are no events I can hook into that happen after all elements are properly rendered.

```
<div id="app">
    <template>
        <el-tabs tab-position="left" class="tabs">
            <el-tab-pane label="Tab1">
                <el-button @click="reflowChart">Reflow chart</el-button>
                <highcharts ref="highchart" :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
            </el-tab-pane>
            <el-tab-pane label="Tab2">
                Test
            </el-tab-pane>
        </el-tabs>
    </template>
</div>
```

I have reproduced the problem here:
https://codepen.io/AlexisSK/pen/XQJKMW

Comment: You tried to make the chart as child component and importing it in the component you are showing us? (instead of using `<highcharts...>`). Try to create as child component. 

Btw, I tried using the tricky solution `v-if` in chart when is mounted `<highcharts v-if="isMounted"...>` and renders well...

Comment: I totally agree with @Mikel, and I've answered that question on the ticket you created on the package's GitHub repository. There you can also find description of what is actually happening , and the live example of how to fix the issue. Here is the mentioned ticket: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/issues/107

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick responses, I had tried this and I thought it wasn't working because when developing locally, the bug remained sometimes. When deployed, it is fixed. I believe it is something to do with how webpack serves assets in development mode that made the styles trigger in the wrong order or something..

If anyone knows how webpack-dev-server with Hot Module Replacement can cause this and how to avoid it, I'd be interested to know !